# Moving selected UICollectionView Cell to the centre of collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have collectionview cell as follows. Middle row should be always visible and two other should always be half seen.But, when I click any row at top or bottom, it should occupy middle cell position. How can i do it?

I tired below but it did make selected  cell visible, but not takes to centre.

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      [colctnView_gallery scrollRectToVisible:[[colctnView_gallery   layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] frame] animated:YES];
}
```

[image]w as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ContentInset` of your collectionview:

```
[colctnView_gallery setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

Set `left` and `right`  to 0. `top` and `bottom` should be equal to your (yourCollectionView's section height + spacing) / 2, or if you're just using 1 section `top` and `bottom` should be equal to (yourCollectionView's cell height + spacing) / 2.